# How to determine the highest video resolution and/or bitrate that a device (Android) can playback?

Tags: android, video

I'm working on an app that needs to play multiple MP4 videos. We have transcoded these videos into multiple resolutions in an attempt to provide the best playback experience for our users. For streaming, we also provide HLS for devices that support it, but we also provide the ability for users to download video for offline playback.

My question is: for a given Android device, is there a way for me to programmatically determine what the maximum resolution and/or bitrate that it can handle?

Comment: have you try [CamcorderProfile](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/CamcorderProfile.html) API but this API available from API level 8

Comment: It looks like CamcorderProfile is used to determine the quality of the device's video camera(s). But I'm looking to know what the device is capable of playing back. So, no, that won't help.

Comment: Did you find a solution? I'm looking for an answer me too. All i done, after an hour of research, is to get the screen resolution and if it is > of 1920x1080, I launch my streaming with HD 720p quality. I'm currently testing it, and i don't know if this is the correct way.

Comment: No, I didn't find a solution. We just guess using a process similar to what you are doing. Would be nice if there was an API that would give the max resolution or bitrate. :/